# How to use implementation dependency from dependency in dependent Gradle project?

Tags: java, gradle, build

Recently one of the libraries in my project was released and one of changes was migration of buildscript to Gradle 6. So **compile** became **implementation** and so on. This means that I cannot access previously defined dependency because gradle does not use when compiling my project:

```
implementation group: 'com.newrelic.agent.java', name: 'newrelic-api', version: '5.+'
```

Or can I? Tried something like below but to no avail..

```
implementation(group: 'com.lib', name: 'starter-web', version: '0.+') {
      implementation("com.newrelic.agent.java:newrelic-api")
}
```

Comment: Gradle does not use...what?

Comment: @smac89 Lib A has Lib B defined as implementation . In my project I use Lib A as implementation, but Lib B is not available to me, hence compilation fails when I use classes from it. How can I override Lib A to provide me Lib B with exact same version defined there..

Comment: Don't. If you need `Lib B`, add a dependency for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since they switched from the `compile` configuration `implementation`, you now need to add a dependency on whatever you were depending on.

```
implementation "com.lib:starter-web:0.+"
implementation "com.newrelic.agent.java:newrelic-api"
```

The `compile` configuration is [deprecated](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#tab:configurations), so if the library author switched to `implementation`, then that may mean their usage of `com.newrelic.agent.java:newrelic-api` was an *implementation* detail of `com.lib:starter-web`. You can think of it as the "private" inner workings of the library.

If `com.lib:starter-web` exposed classes or utilities for consumers to use in their projects that made use of `newrelic-api`, then the library author should have used [`api`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_separation) to make it "public".